How to Make Bar Responsive with rotation?
I work on a small website and this website needs a home page, so I started building one, but when I got to building this bar, I didn't know how to make it responsive with all screens, make it in the bottom of screen, or remove the border. I use Nextjs, Tailwind, and CSS.
The Bar is Responsive with big Screen
The Bar is Not Responsive With small screen


// HeroFooter.js
import { ChevronsRight } from "lucide-react";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
const HeroFooter = () => {
  return (
    <section className={`${styles.AdsBar} rotate-6 relative bg-black text-white py-4 text-center bottom-0 left-0 right-0`}>
      <div className="flex  justify-center space-x-4 overflow-hidden">
        {Array.from({ length: 8 }).map((_, index) => (
          <a key={index} href="#" className="text-white px-4 flex gap-1">
            Get Started <span><ChevronsRight/></span>
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default HeroFooter;
// style.module.css
.AdsBar{
    border-radius: 0px 24px 0px 34px;
}



I tried to use chat gpt, but its not working.

try adding class no-wrap on the div with flex

thx a lot! I fix it
